# JQUERY : use a string as a selector

Tags: jquery

Say that this is a pure string .. not a jquery statement :

```
 \"$("[id^='onetidDoclibViewTb']")\"
```

this is a selector stored as a string somewhere.

How can I convert this into a jquery object?

Please think about the question carefully before jumping to conclusions !!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval()` for that,

```
var selector = "$('#mydiv')";
var divSelector = eval(selector);
alert(divSelector.text());
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdLwvmxp/17/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that just store the selector expression in a string. Like

```
var selector = '#mydiv';
var divSelector = $(selector);
alert(divSelector.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the string has always a jquery object in a string, then you could do:

```
var str = "$('#div1')";
var selector = str.substring(3).substring(0, str.length - 5);
var $object = $(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var elem = '\"$("[id^=onetidDoclibViewTb]")\"'.match(/[^\(|\)|"|\$]+/)[0];
 // do stuff with `$(elem)`;
```

```js
var elem = '\"$("[id^=onetidDoclibViewTb]")\"'.match(/[^\(|\)|"|\$]+/)[0]; 
$(elem).css("color", "blue")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="onetidDoclibViewTb">elem</div>
```